# Why dota2 gamestate does not send me the MatchId

Tags: c#-6.0

I'm trying to implement a web to carry statistics of dota2 using GameState Integration of the game itself, but the Map object does not send the property MatchId, always returns or someone knows something about it?

Comment: what library are you using? as far as i know game state integration does not public matchid. whats your code to fetch it?

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/antonpup/Dota2GSI.
But according to what I have read, Dota2 must export such value (MatchId) in a Json object with a POST request, and when I receive this request it is actually there but always its value is zero. I am using Dota2 without internet connection

Comment: i would bet that match ids are for online games only, but you could consume the json directly and see whats inside